# PHP cURL file upload

Tags: php, curl, file-upload

Good morning,

I'm working with a gene similarity online tool, and i need to simulate the user choices by php. In the  online form there are various select box, a textarea(UserData) and a button type file.

So, i'm captured the post data that sends out the online form, and it is this:

```
POSTDATA =-----------------------------114782935826962
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="SMeasure"

3
-----------------------------114782935826962
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="SOntology"

2
-----------------------------114782935826962
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="SFamily"

2
-----------------------------114782935826962
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="IncludeIEA"

1
-----------------------------114782935826962
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="SApproach"

2
-----------------------------114782935826962
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Identifier"

1
-----------------------------114782935826962
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="UserData"


-----------------------------114782935826962
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="InputFile"; filename="CHI2-GR.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Q15942 Q15942
Q15942 P27918
Q15942 P01034
Q15942 P01040
Q15942 P04053
Q15942 P00746
Q15942 P20138
Q15942 P10620
Q15942 P15923
Q15942 Q06481
P27918 Q15942
P27918 P27918
P27918 P01034
P27918 P01040
P27918 P04053
P27918 P00746
P27918 P20138
P27918 P10620
P27918 P15923
P27918 Q06481
P01034 Q15942
P01034 P27918
P01034 P01034
P01034 P01040
P01034 P04053
P01034 P00746
P01034 P20138
P01034 P10620
P01034 P15923
P01034 Q06481
P01040 Q15942
P01040 P27918
P01040 P01034
P01040 P01040
P01040 P04053
P01040 P00746
P01040 P20138
P01040 P10620
P01040 P15923
P01040 Q06481
P04053 Q15942
P04053 P27918
P04053 P01034
P04053 P01040
P04053 P04053
P04053 P00746
P04053 P20138
P04053 P10620
P04053 P15923
P04053 Q06481
P00746 Q15942
P00746 P27918
P00746 P01034
P00746 P01040
P00746 P04053
P00746 P00746
P00746 P20138
P00746 P10620
P00746 P15923
P00746 Q06481
P20138 Q15942
P20138 P27918
P20138 P01034
P20138 P01040
P20138 P04053
P20138 P00746
P20138 P20138
P20138 P10620
P20138 P15923
P20138 Q06481
P10620 Q15942
P10620 P27918
P10620 P01034
P10620 P01040
P10620 P04053
P10620 P00746
P10620 P20138
P10620 P10620
P10620 P15923
P10620 Q06481
P15923 Q15942
P15923 P27918
P15923 P01034
P15923 P01040
P15923 P04053
P15923 P00746
P15923 P20138
P15923 P10620
P15923 P15923
P15923 Q06481
Q06481 Q15942
Q06481 P27918
Q06481 P01034
Q06481 P01040
Q06481 P04053
Q06481 P00746
Q06481 P20138
Q06481 P10620
Q06481 P15923
Q06481 Q06481
-----------------------------114782935826962
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Submit"

Submit
-----------------------------114782935826962--
```

My php code is simply this:

```
<?php 

$url = 'http://web.cbio.uct.ac.za/ITGOM/tools/itgomEngine.php';     

$postData = array();
$postData['SMeasure'] = '3';
$postData['SOntology'] = '2';
$postData['SFamily'] = '2';
$postData['IncludeIEA'] = '1';
$postData['SApproach'] = '2';
$postData['Identifier'] = '1';
$postData['UserData'] = "";
$postData['InputFile'] = '@C:/Users/Matteo/Desktop/prova_uniprot/CHI2-GR.txt';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;

?>
```

I can set correctly the select options, but i get the error "Txt files only are allowed in the input" when i try to set a file. 
If i try this:

```
$postData['InputFile'] = '@C:/Users/Matteo/Desktop/prova_uniprot/CHI2-GR.txt;type=text/plain';
```

i get the error "No genes list in input". Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: I'm using EasyPHP 14.1 VC9 with a support up to PHP 5.4

Comment: I've tried with EasyPHP 14.1 VC11 with a support up to PHP 5.6, the CURLFile Object, but i get always the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you get this error?

Comment: I get (from online tool response) the error "For the gene list file, only txt format are recommended!". This is very strange because the input file is clearly a txt file!

Comment: How do we know if the forms submitted or not? Is there any message appears when posting through cURL? I don't get any message instead the whole webpage.

Comment: Thanks for reply! The form is not submitted, and i get this error on top of the page response as you can see here: [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/81z3h3kgk8gkguu/Screenshot%202014-04-29%2012.19.36.png). If the code worked, you should get a page like this [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/v7c7fcfep64y37j/Screenshot%202014-04-29%2012.23.56.png)

Comment: You don't get this message error?

Comment: Doing some tests, I've found that with the instruction '@C:\Users\Matteo\Desktop\test.txt', he send a file of type "application/octet-stream" not "plain/text"

Comment: So changing the file type worked?

Comment: No, i'm get the error 'Running fails! Gene list, i.e., a list of interesting genes is missing'. Is there a way to specify the contents of the file?

Comment: This is the same error i'm getting using [`HURL.IT`](http://www.hurl.it/)

Comment: It is as if he took an empty file

Comment: But i have contents on on my file

Comment: I checked the $ FILES variable, and the file has a size greater than zero, then there is content. You know there is a way to specify the content through code?

Comment: Offcourse you can using the file system functions like `fwrite`, `fopen` check the manual.

Comment: I've tried this: $fp = fopen('C:\Users\Matteo\Desktop\test.txt', "w") and curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp), but i get only "1" in the response of curl :(

Comment: But did you actually write something? Currently it seems you just open the file for writing but you didn't write anything there

Comment: I've tried also: $fp = fopen('C:\Users\Matteo\Desktop\test.txt', "r") and receive the warning: "curl_setopt(): the provided file handle is not writable". I always get only "1" as response, for this i've tried with a write mode

Comment: Sorry, with a read mode i receiver the error "Running fails! Gene list, i.e., a list of interesting genes is missing" and the warning

Comment: I've tried this "--data-urlencode "InputFile@test.txt" from curl command line and it would seem to set up the file properly. Have you idea how it turns into php code?

Comment: So what response did you get from `cURL cli`? Also `InputFile@test.txt` seems relative path?

Comment: I've tried to set only InputFile and i see that the value of InputFile in the form is set correctly. Yes, this is a relative path

Comment: Could show your full cURL command that you have tried.

Comment: curl --data-urlencode "InputFile@test.txt" http://web.cbio.uct.ac.za/ITGOM/tools/itgomEngine.php

Comment: Yeah this sets the value but it doesn't mean this sends the information successfully try adding/appending more fields.

Comment: I've tried to include all fields, but not work. I get always the form, not the results page

Answer (score 0):

Any updates on this?  I just tested your original code with an alternate file:

`$postData['InputFile'] = '@C:/Users/../test.txt';`

and it is working just fine.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've tried this: $postData['InputFile'] = '@C:\Users\Matteo\Desktop\test.txt', but i always get the same error. My code is working on EasyPHP, is there any special setting on php.ini? When you run my code you get a table of similarity, or simply a form?

Comment: I get (from online tool response) the error "For the gene list file, only txt format are recommended!". This is very strange because the input file is clearly a txt file